# Data atual Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Preciso pegar a data atual do sistema. Utilizo **Angular** 2.

Tentei a seguinte validação, porém sem sucesso.

```
var now = new Date;

if(dataInicial > now.getFullYear() + now.getMonth() + now.getDate()){
    alert("Data inicial maior que a final!");
}
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: a variavel dataInicial é do tipo String ou tipo Date ?

Answer (score 1):

Como o seu objetivo ao que parece é comparar as duas datas, se ambas forem do tipo Date, existe uma forma simples de fazer isso é compará-las usando milissegundos  ex:

```
dataInicial.getTime() > now.getTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

Uso o angular 3, mas tente isso no 2:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import * as moment from 'moment'

@Pipe({
   name: 'formatDate'
})
export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(date: any, args?: any): any {
     let d = new Date(date)
     return moment(d).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

   }
}
```

No html:

```
<p>{{ date | formatDate }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um componente chamado [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) do angular, ele permite melhor manipulação de datas, através da seguinte sintax:

```
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione os parenteses no **new Date()** que retornará a data atual. Uma outra forma é você utilizar o **momemt.js** fazendo assim: **moment(new Date()).utc().toDate()** você já seta o utc na data e também retorna a data atual.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static obterDataAtual() {
    const date = new Date();

    const ano = date.getFullYear();
    const mes = date.getMonth();
    const dia = date.getDate();

    let mesValor = '';
    let diaValor = '';

    mesValor = ((mes < 10) ? '0' : '').concat(mes.toString())
    diaValor = ((dia < 10) ? '0' : '').concat(dia.toString())

    return ano.toString().concat('-').concat(mesValor).concat('-').concat(diaValor);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Parece que você quer comparar a data sem o horário, portanto você pode fazer algo do tipo.

```
let now = new Date();
if (now.toLocaleDateString() > dataComparacao.toLocaleDateString()) {
    alert('Data atual maior que a data de comparação');
}
```

O método [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) transforma seu objeto `Date` em uma `string` formatada de acordo com o *locale* do navegador ignorando o horário.

Recomendo também a utilização do [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) que facilita muito operações com data/hora.